# How to load and write to Postgres database in Apache Spark

Tags: hibernate, apache-spark

I'm brand new to Apache Spark and I could use some high-level help on how to interface with a Postgres database. I'm planning to write my Spark job in Java.

In my main application, I'm using Hibernate ORM to interface with the database. The schema generally looks as follows:

```
"pages" table
+----+---------+---------------+--------------------+-------------+
| id | content | lastaccessed  |        url         | pagerank_id |
+----+---------+---------------+--------------------+-------------+
|  1 | abc123  | 1511326589645 | http://google6.com | <TBD>       |
+----+---------+---------------+--------------------+-------------+

"outlinks" table ("inlinks" has same structure)
+---------+-------------------+
| page_id |     outlinks      |
+---------+-------------------+
|       1 | http://yahoo.com  |
|       1 | http://google.com |
+---------+-------------------+
```

So pages have a one to many relationship with inlinks and outlinks and a one to one relationship with PageRank.

I want to create a simple Spark job that computes the PageRank for each page and then writes that value to the "pagerank" table and updates each page's pagerank_id with its corresponding value in the pagerank table.

**I have a few questions:**

1. Can I use Hibernate to load the Postgres data into a Spark RDD?
2. If not, must I use something like [`DataFrameReader.jdbc()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/index.html)? If this is the case, how do I do a joined load of the page/inlinks/outlinks tables so I can access have a list of pages each with a set of inlinks and outlinks?
3. Once I compute the pagerank for each page, how do I write the value to the "pagerank" table and update each page's pagerank_id with the corresponding value in the pagerank table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataFrameReader supports loading of a single Table only. Hence, your approach should be

1. Use DataFrameReader , load all tables (pages/outlinks/inlinks) and create separate DataSets
2. Do the join and apply Business logic
3. Use DataFrameWriter to write the content back to PostgreSQL

DataFrameWriter doesn't supports any updates. It can either append to or overwrite existing table.

One approach could be you can create a temporary table , write the data and then handle the rest of the logic in database.